# Boolean fields not getting updated

Tags: sql, go, go-gorm

I'm trying to update my entire database by batching all the changes in my request using *Updates* from gorm. All the fields are getting updated except for the bool values. No error is being thrown too by the database.

This is my struct

```
type Client struct {
    ClientID                    string `json:"client_id"`
    FirstName                   string `json:"first_name"`
    LastName                    string `json:"last_name"`
    Email                       string `json:"email"`
    Telephone                   string `json:"telephone"`
    AcceptNotification          bool   `json:"accept_notification"`
    Verfied                     bool   `json:"verified"`
}
```

and the code to update client is

```
func (b *Client) UpdateClient(request models.Client) (err error) {
    db := b.DB
    result := db.Table("client").
        Where("client_id = ? AND store_id = ?", request.ClientID, request.StoreID).
        Updates(request)
    if result.Error != nil {
        return result.Error
    }
    return nil
}
```

In the documentation it says

> When update with struct, GORM will only update non-zero fields, you might want to use map to update attributes or use Select to specify fields to update

What could be the issue? What is the solution?

Comment: Are you setting all the bool fields to `true`? Because if not, if you are trying to update columns to `false` then you need to use a map, or pointer-to-bool fields, because `false` is the zero-value of the bool type, and as you already quoted: *"GORM will only update non-zero fields"*

Comment: Setting pointer to bool has helped. Any reason why gorm updates only non-zero fields?

Comment: Presumably because the author(s) wanted to reduce the load on the database by sending only fields that are explicitly set, which, if you ask me, is not a good strategy in Go since many zero values are also valid values and it is impossible to be able to tell if a zero value was set or not. The author made their choice and it is what it is... but that's just a guess, if you want to really know you should ask them.

Answer (score 0):

You can't update zero value using struct (you should use a map instead). [From the doc](https://gorm.io/docs/update.html#Updates-multiple-columns):

> Updates multiple columns Updates supports update with struct or
> map[string]interface{}, when updating with struct it will only update
> non-zero fields by default
>
> ```
> // Update attributes with `struct`, will only update non-zero fields
> db.Model(&user).Updates(User{Name: "hello", Age: 18, Active: false})
> // UPDATE users SET name='hello', age=18, updated_at = '2013-11-17 21:34:10' WHERE id = 111;
>
> // Update attributes with `map`
> db.Model(&user).Updates(map[string]interface{}{"name": "hello", "age": 18, "active": false})
> // UPDATE users SET name='hello', age=18, active=false, updated_at='2013-11-17 21:34:10' WHERE id=111;
> ```
>
> NOTE When update with struct, GORM will only update non-zero fields,
> you might want to use map to update attributes or use Select to
> specify fields to update